# How to execute code after an exception has been caught in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm running a function in AWS Lambda in which I have a try catch block implemented.

```
try {
  // do something
} catch(err) {
  myData.error = err;
}

//continue to execute
```

How can I avoid lambda from aborting execution?

Comment: You will have to show the actual code and explain where you want to protect from an exception.  Synchronous exceptions are easy to catch.  Asynchronous exceptions need different treatment.

Comment: Actually, the problem is in Lambda workflow. Inside the try statement I call a method responsible for parsing this object, named "_parseObject". When an exception is thrown in _parseObject, Lambda stop the execution before the catch statement do.

Comment: If you want a better chance for help here on stack overflow, then put your ACTUAL code that has the problem in your question.  We do massively better here with questions that contain your actual code than we do with theoretical questions because actual code is so much more specific as to the real problem and advice can also be so much more specific to your exact situation.  Your theoretical question requires an entire book on error handling.  Your exact code probably requires a few lines of suggested code to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the finally statement like this and put the code you want executed inside the finally block

```
try {
  // do something
} 
catch(err) {
  myData.error = err;
}
finally {
  //add the code you want executed here 
}
```